# Read data from mongo DB using scala for list of case classes

Tags: mongodb, scala, salat

I am new to mongoDB and scala,

I have created case clase like

```
case class ABC(value1:String, Value2:String, Value3:Int)
```

and

```
case class ListOfABC(listofABC: List[ABC])
```

I have created  implicit formater for json to string and vice versa for both classes

```
implicit formater..
```

and I am making call on ListOFABC in DAO object...but I am not getting result I am getting "List()" as output

can anybody sugget any working example of such scenario.. Or my design is right? I mean creating base class and making List of that class?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [casbah](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.0/) ans [Salat](https://github.com/salat/salat/wiki/SalatDAO)

> SalatDAO is a simple extensible DAO pattern that you can use out of
>   box or as the basis for your own DAO implementation.
>
> casbah is Scala toolkit for MongoDB

There are plenty of examples for example in [here](https://github.com/tc/casbah-salat-maven-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/salat/App.scala)

```
import com.novus.salat._
import com.novus.salat.dao._
import com.novus.salat.global._

import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._

case class Employee(_id:ObjectId = new ObjectId, name: String, age: Option[Int]=None, annual_salary: Option[BigDecimal]=None)

object EmployeeDAO
  extends SalatDAO[Employee, ObjectId](collection = MongoConnection()("salat_test")("employees"))

object App{
  def main(args:Array[String]){
    val employee = Employee(name="Foo")

    val id = EmployeeDAO.insert(employee)
    println("Inserted id:" + id)

    val found = EmployeeDAO.findOne(MongoDBObject("name" -> "Foo"))
    println("Found record for name ->Foo:" + found)

    val dbo = grater[Employee].asDBObject(employee)
    println("Converted DBObject:" + dbo)
  }
}
```